# gtkmm 3 Xorg TreeView inside a box inside a ScrolledWindow does not render icons correctly

Tags: gtk, x11, gnome, gtkmm, xorg

I am trying to design a widget where a tree view and other widgets share a vertical box inside a scrolled window:

[image: diagram]

The tree view has a text column and an icon column. The icon column stops rendering after a certain number of rows. The point where it stops is consistent. The number of rows actually rendered depends on the size of the icon. Making the icon smaller will render more rows. I have already seen it stop rendering in the middle of an icon.

With 40 x 40 pixel icons, around 400 rows are rendered correctly if I try to render 500 rows. The number of rows I try to render also effects the outcome: for some high number of rows (10000+ rows), I get segmentation faults and for another big number of rows, the rendering works.

If the tree view is placed directly inside the scrolled window, everything always renders correctly. I tried putting the treeview inside a fixed sized scrolled window inside the box, inside the scrolled window, but the results were similarly bugged.

Here is what it looks like when it stops rendering after 389 rows:

[image: Here is what it looks like when it stops rendering after 389 rows]

Any help figuring out the problem or finding a way around the problem would be appreciated.

Below is a small demo app of the problem. It uses gtkmm 3 on Linux.

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

#include <thread>

#include <gtkmm.h>

class model_columns : public Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord
{
public:
     model_columns()
     {
     add(m_col_desc);
     add(m_col_topic_type_icon);
     }

     Gtk::TreeModelColumn<std::string> m_col_desc;
     Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf>> m_col_topic_type_icon;
};

class test: public Gtk::Window
{
public:
     test();

private:
     Gtk::ScrolledWindow m_scrolled_window;
     Gtk::ScrolledWindow m_scrolled_window_1;
     Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> m_ref_list_model;
     model_columns m_model_columns;
     Gtk::TreeView m_tree_view;
     Gtk::Box m_box;
};
```

test.cpp

```cpp
#include "test.h"

#include <iostream>

test::test()
{
     resize(1050, 1000);
     add(m_scrolled_window);
     m_scrolled_window.add(m_box);

     m_box.set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
     m_box.pack_start(m_tree_view, true,  true);

     m_ref_list_model = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_model_columns);
     m_tree_view.set_model(m_ref_list_model);
     m_tree_view.append_column("Desc1", m_model_columns.m_col_topic_type_icon);
     m_tree_view.append_column("Desc2", m_model_columns.m_col_desc);
     m_tree_view.set_headers_visible(false);

     auto icon = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file("circle.png");
     icon = icon->scale_simple(40,
                              40,
                              Gdk::INTERP_BILINEAR);
     for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 500; i++)
     {
     Gtk::TreeModel::Children::iterator iter = m_ref_list_model->append();
     Gtk::TreeModel::Row row = *iter;
     row[m_model_columns.m_col_desc] = std::to_string(i);
     row[m_model_columns.m_col_topic_type_icon] = icon;
     }
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <giomm/application.h>

#include "test.h"

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
     Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.test_app");
     test test_i;
     app->run(test_i);
     return 0;
}
```

makefile

```
EXECUTABLE=test_app
CFLAGS=-c -Wall 

CC=g++
SOURCES = main.cpp test.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
$(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs`

.cpp.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@  `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags` -g 

clean:
rm -rf *.o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

[Icon file used by app at run time named circle.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdei5.jpg)

Update:
System used: Ubuntu 22.04
gtkmm version: 3.24.5
display server: Xorg X11

The problem is not present when using wayland.